# punctuation after the word say

Tags: punctuation, commas, quotations

How do I punctuate the following sentence in parentheses: (Just stand up and say cancel that.)  Do I need to put the "cancel that" in quotes and a comma after say and a capital "C"? It is an instructional manual.

Comment: If you use quotes, no comma is necessary, unless you hear one when you say it out loud.

Answer (score 0):

1) Reporting something in direct speech: (If the tone is exclamatory, you must use an exclamation mark. If it isn't, a full stop will do the job.)

> Just stand up and say, "Cancel that!"

2)Reporting something in indirect speech:

> Just stand up and *tell him/her/them to* cancel that.

This may be useful: [Punctuation in direct speech](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/punctuation-in-direct-speech)

Comment: The punctuation link says one "should" use a comma after _say_; this is merely opinion, and many disagree. It's in fact optional. Not that keeps anybody from saying it's definitely required or definitely forbidden. For most people, punctuation is grammar, and grammar is a matter of opinion.

Comment: ... It's definitely not required. Or forbidden.

Comment: I didn't know that. Since English isn't my native language, I rely completely on teachers and textbooks for grammar. This piece of information came from a textbook that I had referred to. Most of the sources on the internet also mention the same point.